# DevDay 2018: 5 usuários que melhoram mais postagens

Tags: debate

Fico feliz em compartilhar que *a Stack Overflow* está patrocinando a conferência [DevDay 2018](https://devday.devisland.com/). Como parte do patrocínio, temos 5 ingressos que os membros da nossa comunidade podem ganhar!

Nós concederemos os ingressos para os 5 usuários que melhorarem o maior número de perguntas e respostas no **Stack Overflow em português** a partir de agora (08/08/2018) até 22/08/2018.

As demais regras da campanha são quase as mesmas do ano passado. Algumas notas extras:

- "Melhorar" significa que a postagem aprimorada deve receber pelo menos 4 votos positivos após a edição.
- Não há restrições para isso, qualquer usuário pode participar.
- Nós fornecemos apenas o ingresso, o resto é com você.
- A conferência será realizada no dia 01/09/2018, na [Escola de - Engenharia da UFMG, em Belo Horizonte](https://www.eng.ufmg.br/portal/).
- Os vencedores serão anunciados na sexta-feira, 24 de Agosto.
- Nós usaremos a mesma *query* para encontrar os vencedores como foi usado no ano passado:

  > PrimUpvotes + (5 * Accepts) + (10 * DvUpvotes) + (15 * DvAccepts)
  >   PrimUpvotes: "Votes em uma postagem com 0 pontos antes de uma edição"
  >   Accepts: "Resposta aceita após uma edição"
  >   DvUpvotes: "Votos em uma postage com downvotes antes de uma edição"
  >   DvAccepts: "Aceitação em uma postagem com downvotes antes de uma edição"

O que você ainda está fazendo no Meta? :)

Boa sorte e divirta-se!

Comment: Da hora hein !!! Espero a galera lá no DevDay... Vou ser palestrante e quero o pessoal na minha palestra hein... Sala 3 13:30

Comment: Os Portugueses ficam a espera de um patrocínio em Portugal ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O concurso acabou! Tenho o privilégio de anunciar os vencedores do ingresso deste ano para a conferência DevDays de 2018. Por favor, junte-se a mim para parabenizar:

- [Yoda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/94746/yoda)
- [Dherik](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4492/dherik)
- [Francisco](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/62269/francisco)
- [João Paulo Pulga](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23395/jo%c3%a3o-paulo-pulga)
- [mutlei](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/18243/mutlei)

**Para os vencedores** - entre em contato comigo para obter instruções sobre como conseguir seus ingressos! Você pode me enviar um email em jgarza @ stackoverflow.com

**Por favor note**
Todos os vencedores foram notificados do seu prêmio. Eles foram enviados por e-mail pelos patrocinadores da conferência diretamente. Obrigado a todos que participaram!

Comment: Juan, não seria mais "seguro" notificá-los por seus perfis, assim, evitaria que outros se passassem por eles lhe enviando email?

Comment: @Articuno Eu poderia, mas posso verificar seus endereços de e-mail facilmente. Vou dar a eles alguns dias para responder e, se eu não souber deles, posso contatá-los diretamente. Obrigado pela sua sugestão!

Comment: Olha, por incrivel que pareça: Eu não tava nem sabendo desse concurso! Estou lisonjeado! Mas acho que não vai dar pra mim ir! Vou confirmar com familiares e trabalho aqui antes de tudo!

Comment: Eu vou rejeitar o convite de ir no evento. Valeu. Problemas demais aqui pra mim :(

Comment: @mutlei Obrigado por me avisar. É uma pena que você não possa comparecer, mas espero que as coisas melhorem em breve.

Comment: @JuanM, puxa só vi agora! Não poderia ir, mas fico feliz de ter ficado entre os 5 primeiros. PS.: creio que não tenha recebido o e-mail, dei uma olhada aqui e não recebi nada relacionado ao DevDay. No mais, parabéns pela iniciativa.

Answer (score 2):

#### Você irá usar o ingresso?

[A campanha DevDays 2018](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7242/) está terminando. Como sugestão para tornar o processo de encontrar os usuários para os quais devemos enviar os ingressos rápido e fácil, pedimos aos usuários que irão participar da conferência no caso de vencerem a competição, que por gentileza deem upvote nesta resposta.

Isso irá ajudar no processo de dar o prêmio às pessoas que realmente irão usá-lo!

Se você não for à conferência, você ainda pode ser aquele que fez mais edições úteis do que qualquer outro :)

Comment: Se você está querendo ir à conferência, avise-nos! Vota a resposta para que saibamos que você está interessado.